# Prometheus Custom Metrics , trying to send logs from all other endpoints to /metrics

Tags: go, prometheus

I have set up a boilerplate Prometheus Custom metrics with a /metrics endpoint and created  Prometheus.YAML  file

from my understanding, there are 4 kinds of custom metrics counter, gauge, histogram , and summary.

how would I go about it so that when /metrics is hit, im able to see logs from all other endpoints?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "tracker/config"
    "tracker/db"
    "tracker/handlers"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promauto"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

//======================================================================

var totalRequests = prometheus.NewCounterVec(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "total_requests",
    Help: "Total requests",
}, []string{"method", "endpoint"})

//======================================================================

var httpDuration = promauto.NewHistogramVec(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
    Name:    "http_request_duration_seconds",
    Help:    "Duration of HTTP requests in seconds",
    Buckets: []float64{.1, .25, .5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10},
}, []string{"method", "endpoint"})

//======================================================================

func prometheusMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)

        totalRequests.With(prometheus.Labels{"method": r.Method, "endpoint": r.URL.Path}).Inc()
    })
}
//======================================================================

func init() {
    prometheus.Register(totalRequests)
    prometheus.Register(httpDuration)
}

//======================================================================

func main() {
 config.SetAppConfig(os.Getenv("CONFIG_CLASS"))

    // Connect to db
    db.Connect()

    // Router
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Path("/metrics").Handler(promhttp.Handler())
    
    r.HandleFunc("/status", handlers.CreateStatus).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/status/{id}", handlers.GetStatus).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/status/{id}/latest", handlers.GetLatest).Methods("GET")
    log.Println("Listening on port 8080")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "logs" and "from all other endpoints"?

Comment: You don't need to `prometheus.Register` metrics that have been created with `promauto`. You  may want to use `promauto` to define `totalRequests` as you have with `httpDuration`.

Comment: @DazWilkin for example when someone posts a status,  im logging the JSON payload and time, when someone gets a status, I'm logging the transactionID and time if we went into the k8 culster and did a kubectl logs <podname> -n <namespace> all logs can be read

so 
when /metrics is hit we are returning logs from all endpoints when they have been hit

Comment: Logs and metrics are different. When you are e.g. "logging the JSON payload and time when someone gets a status" in your code then you will want to also e.g. increment a Prometheus Counter to measure some subset of the same event. The "someone gets a status" event in your application is (1) logged; **and** (2) Counted. In this case (!) the log entries will contain much metadata about the event and some message, whereas the metrics will help you determine e.g. how many status updates succeeded as a proportion of the total (you should count either successes or failures and totals).